# How to open tabbar BY click notification

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to open APP in specific tabbar by click notification on lock screen

Now I used

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)
{
    print("user clicked on the notification")
    if let tabBarController = self.window!.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
        tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2
    }
}
```

and it have error

```
Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'window'
```

on Swift5, Is it have better way?

Comment: Is your app in SwiftUI and is it created create on Xcode 11+?

Comment: Create By Storyboard and Xcode 11

Answer (score 0):

This seemed easier and worked for me:

```
if let tabBarController = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter({$0.isKeyWindow}).first?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
    tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2
}
```

Comment: if let tabBarController = ... {  ta.. = 2 }else{ print("Error") }  ///Then it print error Why?

Comment: I used UITabbar --> UINav --> UIViewController AS your code key window is UINav

Comment: Yes, it depends on the app structure. This code gives you the rootViewController. From there you need to get to your `tabBarController`. From the question you gave the code that say rootViewController was indeed tabBarController.

Answer (score 0):

solve it!!!

```
DispatchQueue.main.async{
        let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first

        if var topController = keyWindow?.rootViewController {
            while let presentedViewController = topController.presentedViewController {
                topController = presentedViewController

                let tabbarController = presentedViewController as! UITabBarController
                tabbarController.selectedIndex = 2
            }
        }
    }
```